# Does Chainlink fees increase with the number of Random words requested?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I am writing a smart contract that requires a number of random words to be generated via the Chainlink VRF.

Now, according to Chailink VRFV2Consumer contract, you can request the number of random words like so:

```
uint32 numWords =  2;
```

My question is, will it cost more if you increase the number of random words requested or will the fees remain same? I haven't seen any explanation of this yet so I think it would be helpful for developers if they knew how this would impact the fees.

Answer (score 2):

As they mentioned in their documents yes it depends on the number random values you asked. 
Read the document linked below carefully. 
https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/ 
Gas price:
Callback gas: 
Verification gas: 
These variables depend on current network conditions, your specified limit on callback gas, and the number of random values in your request. The cost of each request is final only after the transaction is complete, but you define the limits you are willing to spend for the request with the following variables: